# Finding tangent vector for a curve at a given point

Tags: derivatives, vectors

For a problem like this where I have to find the tangent vector at the point $(0,0,1)$:

$$r(t) = \sin(t)i + (t^2 − t)j+\sqrt{1 + t}k$$

I know I would take the derivative of the problem, but would I substitute $1$ for each $t$ value, or would I substitute $0$ for the $t$ values at $i$ and $j$, and $1$ for the $t$ value at $k$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to figure out which value of $t$ corresponds to the point $(0,0,1)$, that is, which number $t$ solves the equation $r(t) = (0,0,1)$?

Then take the derivative of $r$ with respect to $t$, and plug in the value that you found above. The result will be a tangent vector for the curve at the point $(0,0,1)$.

What do you get?

Comment: oh okay, so t = 0, and I plug in zero for each value of r'(t)?

Comment: Yeah, you plug in $0$ for each value of $t$ in $r'(t)$.

Comment: Okay thank you for the help

Comment: No problem. :) Glad it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Neither. You must find the value of $t$ for which your function $r(t)$ is at the point $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: Just to clarify, the OP must *first* find the value of $t$ that creates $(0,0,1)$. He then continues from there.